# How to constrain the pose of an interactive marker in RVIZ?

Tags: ros, rviz, interactive-markers

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

Do you have any idea about how to constrain the pose of an interactive marker in RVIZ?

I want to stop the shape when it reaches a specified position.

Thank you!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/224299/how-to-constrain-the-pose-of-an-interactive-marker-in-rviz?/) by [masihec](https://answers.ros.org/users/24631/masihec/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2016-01-17

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is possible using the feedback callback described in [this tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/rviz/Tutorials/Interactive%20Markers%3A%20Writing%20a%20Simple%20Interactive%20Marker%20Server).

Python example:

```
class myInteractivemarker:
    def __init__(self):
         # Define your marker....
         my_marker = InteractiveMarker()
         ......

          # Set feedback callback
          self.server.insert(my_marker, self.processFeedback)

    def processFeedback(self, feedback):
         # Trim the position in X of the marker
         if feedback.pose.position.x < 0:
             feedback.pose.position.x = 0
         if feedback.pose.position.x > 10:
             feedback.pose.position.x = 10
        # Apply changes to the marker.
         self.server.applyChanges()
```

---

Originally posted by [Javier V. Gómez](https://answers.ros.org/users/5464/javier-v.-g%C3%B3mez/) with karma: 1305 on 2016-01-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [masihec](https://answers.ros.org/users/24631/masihec/) on 2016-01-18**:
Thank you Javier for your answer!

Actually, i tried as you specified but it doesn't work (no changing is done). I didn't find what is wrong exactly, i'm new in ROS so may be i'm making a mistake somewhere!

I will be grateful if you can help me in this.

Here is the code that i'm using right now.

**Comment by [adamconkey](https://answers.ros.org/users/27913/adamconkey/) on 2022-06-07**:
This won't work because the feedback message you receive is just reporting info about the state of the interactive marker and has no write capabilities on the server. @sai-krishna's answer is correct, where you have to call setPose and applyChanges on the server.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi Masihec,
You have to use **server.setPose( feedback.marker_name, pose )** to change/constrain the position of Interactive marker. A sample code is given below.

```
def processFeedback(feedback):
     # Trim the position in X of the marker
     if feedback.pose.position.x < 0:
         feedback.pose.position.x = 0
     if feedback.pose.position.x > 10:
         feedback.pose.position.x = 10
    # Apply changes to the marker.
     server.setPose( feedback.marker_name, feedback.pose)
     server.applyChanges()
```

---

Originally posted by [Sai Krishna](https://answers.ros.org/users/36649/sai-krishna/) with karma: 31 on 2018-10-23

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1